# Как узнать где происходит обмен с roistat?

Tags: php, битрикс, cp1251, crm

Есть сайт на 1с - Битрикс , сделан еще в кодировке **win-1251**

Проблема в том, что при обмене с roistat файл обмена улетает в кодировке win-1251, отсюда получается вот такая шляпа в админке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.к интеграция делалась давно и другими людьми, я не знаю как мне найти сам файл обмена с ройстат? ( По новым правилам апи сейчас интеграция через модуль, но он не установлен).

***Из ответов ТП***

> В коде формы кнопка размечена следующим классом - bx_bt_submit Такой класс не используется в проксировании форм в вашем проекте. При этом, при нажатии, ваш скрипт ссылается на следующий путь - oncl ick="Stat.SEND_1BUY_CLICK();" Судя по всему, информация о заявке поступает в отдельный файл обработчика заказов на вашем сервере Могли бы вы, пожалуйста, проверить - куда отправляется информация и добавлен ли наш php-скрипт или любой другой при обработке заказов

Как найти эту функцию ***SEND_1BUY_CLICK()*** ?

*Полностью менять кодировку смысла нет, т.к  это трудозатртано, и проблема только с внешним сервисом.*

Comment: А в чем проблема выкачать сайт и искать по файлам?

Comment: проект весит 54 гб ) стоит дебиан, я сделал поиск вот так **find .-name ".php" | xargs grep "send_1buy_click()"** , но поиск не дал результатов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**iconv** не везде почему то работал, весь файл init.php заменил на utf-8, немного переписал передачу параметров., это помогло решить 90% с кодировкой. кстати при передачи, например на ЯМ такой проблемы нету. это особенность ройстат( точнее его недостаток, что он не умеет хавать win1251)

```
function secretfunction(&$event, &$lid, &$arFields)
{
    // AddMessage2Log( print_r($event, true) );
    // AddMessage2Log( print_r($lid, true) );
    // AddMessage2Log( print_r($arFields, true) );

    $title = 'Форма купить в 1 клик';
    // $title = iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $title);
    $comment = $arFields['ITEM_NAME'] . $arFields['QUANTITY'];

    // $comment = iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $comment);
    if ($event == 'FEEDBACK_FORM') {
        $roistatData = array(
            'roistat' => isset($_COOKIE['roistat_visit']) ? $_COOKIE['roistat_visit'] : null,
            'key' => '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
            'title' => $title,
            'comment' =>  iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $comment),
            // 'name'    =>  $name,
            // 'email'   =>  $arFields['EMAIL'],
            'phone' => preg_replace("([^0-9])", "", $arFields['AUTHOR_PHONE']),
            'fields' => array(
                "test" => test,
            ),
        );


    }
}
```

нашел кстати так `grep -rn —include=\*.php 'send_1buy_click' ./`

Answer (score 1):

1) Определяете в каком компоненте лежит темплейт с этой кнопкой
2) Найдите компонент. Если OnClick значит это некая JS-Функция, просмотрите JS фаилы в папке компонента или общий main.js сайта, если он есть на наличие функции Stat.SEND_1BUY_CLICK() и посмотреть к какому скрипту та обращается